# Display balance from an Aion Account

Tags: java, blockchain, aion

I'm trying to get the balance of an account in Aion using the Java API. No matter what I do I can't get a value from the `account` variable.

```
account = "a06f02e986965ddd3398c4de87e3708072ad58d96e9c53e87c31c8c970b211e5";
BigInteger account_balance = api.getChain().getBalance(account).getObject();

System.out.format("%n%s balance is = %d nAmp (over %d AION)%n", 
    account, 
    account_balance, 
    account_balance.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(18)));
```

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your account address in `Address.wrap`.

```
account = Address.wrap("a06f02e9...");
```

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try making an [RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance) call with a JSON request:
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x0","latest"],"id":32}`